# yii2 UrlManager error with last element in url

Tags: yii2, pretty-urls, yii2-urlmanager

How can I set up urlManager rules like that?

- /category/category1/element/
- /category2/element/

Yii perceives the last element as a category.
I need exactly this scheme url.
If you do not put the last slash, then everything is OK, but it is needed

Now i have this rules

```
 'blog/<category:[\w_\/-]+>' => 'blog/category',
 'blog/<category:[\w_\/-]+>/<slug>' => 'blog/post',
```

they do not work. There is an option to parse url and run needed action in controller, but its wrong

Comment: did you try adding it at the end of your rules? I mean `'blog/<category:[\w_\/-]+>/'`

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo no difference.

Comment: Why is last `/` important? May be you have a design issue